# GCC generated crazy program

Tags: c++, gcc

Look this piece of code:

```
vector<Command*> list;
int cur = -1;

if( cur < (list.size()-1) )
{   
    cout<<"redo"<<endl;
    ++cur;
    list[cur]->execute(text);
    cout<<"pos: "<<cur<<" size: "<<list.size()<<endl;
}   
else
{   
    cout<<cur<<" "<<(list.size()-1)<<" "<<( cur > (list.size()-1) )<<endl;
}   
if(-1>2)
    cout<<"true"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"false"<<endl;
```

It's printing:

```
-1 2 1 

false
```

which means:

- `cur = -1`
- `list.size()-1 = 2`
- `cur > list.size()-1  == true`, i.e. `-1 > 2`

but the other if says it's false and math say the same.

My GCC version is: gcc version 4.8.0 (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project)

am I the problem or GCC?

Comment: Where are you checking that cur > list.size() -1 == true?

Comment: What is the data-type of `cur`?

Comment: list.size() is 3 cuz i print cout<<(list.size()-1) and it prints 2

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an unsigned data type.

Comment: vector<Command*> list;
int cur = -1;

Comment: You have mixed signed and unsigned comparisons going on here.  These won't work as you think they should.   Add the `-Wall` flag to gcc, and it will tell you where the problems are.

Comment: yeah it's unsined and signed comparison problem... thx msandiford

Comment: GCC has a perfectly good warning that is emitted when you compare signed to unsigned types for exactly this reason.

Comment: None of the existing answers/comments explain how the second number printed could be "2"... on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ltEZeq) I get "-1 4294967295 0" which is as I'd expect given 4294967295 is `uint32_t(-1)`.  I can't imagine any reason for that to vary (excepting 64bit programs having an even larger number, but not 2).  @briebtag - please post the ***complete*** compilable program producing this output.

Comment: -1 -- code provided does not reproduce problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `cur` is signed and `list.size` is unsigned.

Then in this expression:

```
cur > (list.size()-1)
```

`cur` gets converted to unsigned, so the value is `true`.

---

You may try this simple sample, `c` gets value `false`.

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 1;
bool c = a < b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in 5/9 (rules for binary operators):

> Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>   operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted
>   operands:

...

> Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer
>   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type

So in this case we go through a whole bunch of rules on integral promotion and finally wind up on this one. This says that your `cur` will be promoted to unsigned (the return type from the `size` method), which is a well-defined operation to perform modulo arithmetic. It will then be the largest unsigned int and larger than the size of your container.